# Java - System.setProperty javax.net.ssl.keyStore - Reference to the key file in a Jar

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, truststore

The code as below

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "WS12345._.1.ks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "jNY9vp6iTQ");
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator("WS12345._.1","password"));
```

When I keep the WS12345._.1.ks file in my project folder (while working on eclipse), the code works fine. However, when I need to make similar code changes and get it working on a Jar, it fails to identify the keystore file.

How to add this private key with the code while working with a Jar?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It is a filename, not a URL. But you don't want to do this anyway. You want your certificate out there in a keystore file, where it can be renewed, revoked, etc.